# why do pipenv install uwsgi with different version of python?

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi, pipenv

I am trying to install uwsgi library with `pipenv`

my environment is below and I run on pipenv.

```
(docker_test) ubuntu@ip-10-213-27-94:~/docker_test$ python --version
Python 3.9.10
(docker_test) ubuntu@ip-10-213-27-94:~/docker_test$ pip --version
pip 22.0.3 from /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/docker_test-zaCE99f5/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

But when I try to install `uwsgi` with a command `pipenv install uwsgi`
it seems working with different version of python and only to fail...

```
(docker_test) ubuntu@ip-10-213-27-94:~/docker_test$ pipenv install uwsgi
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:119: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
Installing uwsgi...
Error:  An error occurred while installing uwsgi!
```

I don't understand why.... :-(

Answer (score 0):

this may be because of differnet python version associated with the pip and pipenv.

do use `python -m <pip/pipenv> install uwsgi`